# PostgreSQL trigger syntax error

Tags: postgresql, exception, triggers, plpgsql

I wonder how to use trigger in PostgreSQL with `RAISE SQLSTATE` dynamic instruction?

```
IF i>0 THEN
    RAISE SQLSTATE '23505' USING MESSAGE = 'la planète est déjà occupée (planet_non_free)=(%, %, %)', NEW.galaxie, NEW.systeme_solaire, NEW.position;
END IF;
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Ok, I just found the solution...just surrounded MESSAGE value by parenthesis like this : `MESSAGE = ('la planète..., NEW.position);`

Comment: You should write it up as an answer and accept it. :-)

Comment: What PostgreSQL version is this supposed to be? Also, "It doesn't work" is not a PostgreSQL error message known to me. It should go without saying to include the *actual* error message. If your system runs with a french locale, just run `SET lc_messages='C';` to switch to English for the current session.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use:

```
IF i > 0 THEN
    RAISE SQLSTATE '23505'
    USING MESSAGE = format('la planète est déjà occupée (planet_non_free)=(%s, %s, %s)', NEW.galaxie, NEW.systeme_solaire, NEW.position);
END IF;
```

Then your error message reads:

```
la planète est déjà occupée (planet_non_free)=(<g>, <s>, <p>)
```

.. instead of:

```
("la planète est déjà occupée (planet_non_free)=(%, %, %)",<g>, <s>, <p>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution. I have only to surround `MESSAGE` value with parenthesis :

So :

```
IF i>0 THEN
   RAISE SQLSTATE '23505' USING MESSAGE = 'la planète est déjà occupée (planet_non_free)=(%, %, %)', NEW.galaxie, NEW.systeme_solaire, NEW.position;
END IF;
```

becomes :

```
IF i>0 THEN
   RAISE SQLSTATE '23505' USING MESSAGE = ('la planète est déjà occupée (planet_non_free)=(%, %, %)', NEW.galaxie, NEW.systeme_solaire, NEW.position);
END IF;
```

Simple but I did not saw explicit example with dynamic `MESSAGE` on the web.

Hope this helps

**EDIT :**

Ok sorry, the right syntax is this one :

```
IF i>0 THEN
    RAISE SQLSTATE '23505' USING MESSAGE = 'la planète est déjà occupée (planet_non_free)=(' || NEW.galaxie || ',' || NEW.systeme_solaire || ',' || NEW.position || ')';
END IF;
```

It seems that we can not use `%` with `USING MESSAGE` statement.